# How to merge dictionaries data after Scraping from beautiful soup

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I have been learning Beautiful soup and I tried **scraping** following page https://www.usclimatedata.com/climate/anchorage/alaska/united-states/usak0012
I tried to **scrape** the table based on monthly stats. Fortunately I have come to half of my solution but I don't know how to merge dictionaries at the end. here is my code

```
url = "https://www.usclimatedata.com/climate/united-states/us"
r = requests.get(url)  # request the website url
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')  # beautiful soup object
main_url = "https://www.usclimatedata.com"
usa_state = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url = (link.get('href'))
    if url and '/climate' in url and '/climate/united-states/us' not in url:
        usa_state.append(url)
r = requests.get(main_url + usa_state[1])
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
tables = soup.findAll('table')
for table in tables:
    table_body = table.findAll('tbody')[0]
    main_table_head = table.find_all('thead')[0]
    table_head_rows = main_table_head.findAll('tr')
    month = None
    for table_header in table_head_rows:
        spans = table_header.findAll("span", {"class": "d-none d-sm-block"})
        month = [(span.find('abbr')).text for span in spans]
    table_rows = table_body.findAll('tr')
    for table_row in table_rows:
        table_head = table_row.findAll('th')[0]
        fields = table_head.findAll('span', {"class": "d-none d-lg-block"})
        data = table_row.findAll('td')
        dict_values = {
            'months': month,
            'field': [field.text for field in fields],
            'values': [json.loads(value.string) for value in data]

        }

        print(dict_values)
```

The result from above code is below

```
{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'], 'field': ['Average high in ºF '], 'values': [23, 27, 34, 44, 56, 63]}
{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'], 'field': ['Average low in ºF '], 'values': [11, 14, 19, 29, 40, 48]}
{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'], 'field': ['Days with precipitation '], 'values': [7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 7]}
{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'], 'field': ['Hours of sunshine '], 'values': [78, 114, 210, 254, 268, 288]}
{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'], 'field': ['Av. precipitation in inch '], 'values': [0.73, 0.72, 0.6, 0.47, 0.72, 0.97]}
{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'], 'field': ['Av. snowfall in inch '], 'values': [11, 11, 10, 4, 0, 0]}
{'months': ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Average high in ºF '], 'values': [65, 64, 55, 40, 28, 25]}
{'months': ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Average low in ºF '], 'values': [52, 50, 42, 29, 17, 13]}
{'months': ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Days with precipitation '], 'values': [11, 15, 15, 11, 8, 7]}
{'months': ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Hours of sunshine '], 'values': [255, 184, 128, 96, 68, 49]}
{'months': ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Av. precipitation in inch '], 'values': [1.83, 3.25, 2.99, 2.03, 1.16, 1.11]}
{'months': ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Av. snowfall in inch '], 'values': [0, 0, 0, 8, 13, 17]}
```

Now I want dictionaries to be merged in this format

```
{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Average high in ºF '], 'values': [23, 27, 34, 44, 56, 63, 65, 64, 55, 40, 28, 25]]}
```

and same follows for rest of other table data how can I solve this merging dictionary issue? TIA.

Comment: A solution might be to move your `dict_values` out of the loops and push your data to it.

Comment: any code hint? will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to include month because it always has full month (12). using this way will make your code and results compact and cleaner

```
# for url: /climate/anchorage/alaska/united-states/usak0012
data = {}

for row in soup.select('.monthly_tables tr'):
    if not row.select('td'):
        continue
    key = row.select_one('.d-lg-block').text.strip()
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = []
    for cell in row.select('td'):
        data[key].append(cell.text.strip())

print(data)
```

results:

```
{
  "Average high in ºF": ["23", "27", "34", "44", "56", "63", "65", "64", "55", "40", "28", "25"],
  "Average low in ºF": ["11", "14", "19", "29", "40", "48", "52", "50", "42", "29", "17", "13"],
  "Days with precipitation": ["7", "6", "7", "4", "5", "7", "11", "15", "15", "11", "8", "7"],
  "Hours of sunshine": ["78", "114", "210", "254", "268", "288", "255", "184", "128", "96", "68", "49"],
  "Av. precipitation in inch": ["0.73", "0.72", "0.60", "0.47", "0.72", "0.97", "1.83", "3.25", "2.99", "2.03", "1.16", "1.11"],
  "Av. snowfall in inch": ["11", "11", "10", "4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "8", "13", "17"]
}
```

to select `Average high in ºF` for july

```
julyHi = data['Average high in ºF'][6] # month index starting from 0
print(julyHi) 
# 65
```

to select all value for july

```
for key in data:
    print(data[key][6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "months", "fields", and "values" data into the set, the set will handle the uniqueness.

define set like this at the top

```
months = set()
fields = set()
values = set()
```

and add the value into the desired set like

```
months.add(VALUE_TO_STORE)
```

at the end you can create your output dict like this

```
dict_values = {
    'months': list(months),
    'field': list(field),
    'values': list(values)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be like below. Note this is only for the case if your desired output is consistent like in your example and will not work if your scraped data is dynamic.

```py
...
dict_values = []
for table in tables:
    ...
    # first create a temp variable to hold the values
    temp = {}
    temp["months"] = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    
    for table_row in table_rows:
        ...
        field = [field.text for field in fields]
        values = [json.loads(value.string) for value in data]
        # if there is no field in temp value, we'll create it
        if temp.get("field") is None:
            temp["field"] = field
            temp["values"] = values
        # if field value is already created and months are from Jan to Jun we'll add the values to the front
        elif temp["field"] == field and month == temp["months"][0:6]
            temp["values"] = values + temp["values"]
         # if field value is already created and months are from Jul to Dec we'll add the values to the back
        elif temp["field"] == field and month == temp["months"][6:]
            temp["values"] = temp["values"] + values
    # finally append the temp values
    dict_values.append(temp)
```

Comment: `[{'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Average high in ºF ']}, {'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Average high in ºF ']}, {'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Average high in ºF ']}, {'months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 'field': ['Average high in ºF ']}, ` output goes in this manner according to your answer

Comment: I had some error in my original answer. Try my edited answer.

Comment: i think `elif temp["field"] == field and month == temp["months"][0:6]` here ->month  need to be 'month' is it?

Comment: `month` is the variable you have written in your code. I've redacted it in my code.

Comment: the output is still not convincing one :(